# How to add a link group to update-alternatives?

Tags: system, alternative, update-alternatives

Is it possible to add a custom link group to update-alternatives that is not already there by default?

For example, I want to add Scala and all its supporting binaries as a link group 'scala'.  I'm trying using [this script](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts/blob/cac444cce4abd44ae210440c2834c2fdcaf39da1/install/scala/typesafe-stack-2.0.2-install.sh), but keep getting the error:

```
update-alternatives: error: unknown argument `'
```

I'm not sure what that means, but after troubleshooting the script a bit with no luck, I'm wondering if update-alternatives has a hard-coded list of link groups, that can't be added to, and that doesn't include scala.

Comment: You should add your solution as answer.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer, instead as part of the question (otherwise it shows up as unanswered, and that's bad)

Comment: Done, thanks.  I can't accept it as the answer for 2 days, so will do that then.  Thanks also for the new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:  Yes you can add custom link groups, they're not limited to anything hard-coded by Ubuntu.

My particular problem was a finicky error [in the script](https://github.com/byrongibson/scripts/blob/cac444cce4abd44ae210440c2834c2fdcaf39da1/install/scala/typesafe-stack-2.0.2-install.sh) - I had left spaces after the line continuation backslashes \ at the end of each line in the script, that broke it.  Fixed that, it works now.

Answer (score 4):

you can use:

```
update-alternatives --install <path-to-generic-binary> <generic-binary-name> <path-to-alternatives> <priority>
```

so that for installing scala of different versions, you could do like:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/scala scala /opt/scala-x.x.x/bin/scala 1200
```

***Note:***

*this is an extracted version of the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/144349/97755), from the [accepted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/144349/97755)'s script link.*

*Added here so that the answer be here even if the link breaks in the future.*

Comment: I hava tried the same for scalac, but got the error: sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/scalac scalac /home/alexandr/opt/scala-2.12.2/bin/scalac 1400
update-alternatives: error: alternative scalac can't be master: it is a slave of scala How can I solve it? Creating a direct link is not good for me.

Comment: @Alexandr I have not used Ubuntu for a while, but I think with the same command, slave commands can be added. Please check the man pages.

Comment: by mistake I configured in wrong way 'scala', it included both scala and scalac packages. I removed all configuration for 'scala': sudo update-alternatives --remove-all scala and then, configured them separately. It fixed the error.